# mobile friendly responsive jquery tabs

Tags: jquery, tabs

I am looking for some jquery based plug-in (if available) that automatically changes to responsive collapsible containers from regular tabs for mobile friendliness.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the jQuery Mobile project.  jQuery Mobile is a great start to develop a mobile web application.  An example of collapsible containers can be found in the jquery Mobile docs, [Collapsibles](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/collapsibles/).  If you liked that example checkout [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/).

Comment: Thanks a lot Nick. I will definitely try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, customizable and responsive

[Twitter Bootstrap Tabs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs)

Comment: This seems a perfect solution. I will try this out. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to change the styling per element depending upon specifications. You would have to add these to the bottom of your stylesheet, or create a new stylesheet (eg repsonsive.css), so that it overwrites your default styles depending upon the screensize.

This following media-queries template is only based on screen size. You can use more complex media-queries to target specific device as well.

To Support older browsers (IE), you'd have to use conditional statements to include respond.js or media-queries.js . Media queries will only work with device specifications such as screen, handheld etc...

Eg:

```
/* Large desktop */ 
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }

/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }
```

Answer based on [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/87186/how-would-i-use-a-media-query-to-make-my-entire-theme-responsive-or-fluid) link from a previous stackexchange question.

--

If your preferences goes out to the sole use of a jquery plugin you could use the following:
[ResponseJS](http://responsejs.com/) with this [Jquery plugin](https://github.com/AlessMascherpa/jq-responsive-tabs)